# Log Sql server stored procedure start and end time 

Tags: sql-server, logging, stored-procedures

I have overloaded SQL Server, and I want to make some optimization.

For that purpose I'd like to get some statistics about the start and the finish time of the called stored procedures.

Is there any system table, or maybe other item, where I can get this information from?

Comment: Use the SQL Server Profiler. That will give you all the information you need.

Comment: Please specify the minimum version you need to support. "SQL Server" is not specific enough to answer your question without more prodding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    [procedure] = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
        + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])),
    last_execution_time,
    avg_execution_time = CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,2), total_worker_time * 1.0 / execution_count),
    max_worker_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY avg_execution_time DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [DM Objects - Sys.dm exec query stats](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/DM_Objects_-_Sys.dm_exec_query_stats)

or from http://www.sqlteam.com/Forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=159011:

> ... if you are running on sql 2008 or higher. .....

```
SELECT 

COALESCE(DB_NAME(t.[dbid]),'Unknown') AS [DB Name],
ecp.objtype AS [Object Type],
t.[text] AS [Adhoc Batch or Object Call],
SUBSTRING(t.[text], (qs.[statement_start_offset]/2) + 1,
((CASE qs.[statement_end_offset]
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(t.[text]) ELSE qs.[statement_end_offset] END
- qs.[statement_start_offset])/2) + 1) AS [Executed Statement]
,qs.[last_execution_time] AS [Last Exec Time]
,qs.[creation_time] AS [Creation Time]

FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_cached_plans ecp 
            ON qs.plan_handle = ecp.plan_handle
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS t
where
    ecp.objtype = 'Proc'

order by [Last Exec Time] desc
```

Comment: Using Sql Server 2008 R2, have some problem with syntax error in "Cross Apply ..." string - "Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Try executing in master. I suspect the user database where you are executing this from is in an earlier compatibility mode. Is this a database that has been upgraded from SQL Server 2000? Any reason it's still in 80 compat mode? What does `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID();` yield?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually by creating your own system log table then inserting the new row at the start of the stored procedure and then updating it at the end example:

```
INSERT INTO systemLog (proc,start) VALUES ('My Proc',GETDATE())
SELECT @logid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

--Do stuff here

UPDATE systemLog SET enddate = GETDATE() WHERE logid = @logid
```

Advantage of this is if a stored proc fails it wont update the system log enddate

Comment: This can get really chatty on a busy system, and while the DMVs don't track every single invocation of each proc (and don't tell you about exceptions), I think they already contain much of the information Johnny_D is after without introducing custom code to all of the procedures in the system, including stats on those procedures since the last time the system was restarted (adding your logging, it would only work going forward). In general I agree with having logging in critical procs but it shouldn't be on by default, enabled only with a certain flag.

Comment: Yes it does although our requirements are slightly different in that we have to watch the values going in and out of SP's as none of the queries are known till run time. A solution to this was to have a logging flag to decide whether any SP's should be logging